# Detecting a click on the Registration Plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there any way to detect a click on the registration plugin's submit button? I know that some (the like button) trigger an event that can be subscribed to.

I am using the XFBML plugin.

**Edit**:  I need to direct facebook's response to a URL outside of the load balancer, while sending the user to the same page, but inside the load balancer, when they submit. The Registration Plugin only allows me to have one redirect-uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are try to capture the user who gave up registration.

There not a call back for that as it happens for like button when liked. Even you capable do it with iframe manipulation somehow it is against [same origin policy](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Same-origin-policy/132789400090109), this means you will be blocked.

however, you have cancel url from client side easily you can do on the server side consider logging users step: that you redirected to registration and doesn't come back.

Comment: I am actually going the other direction - I need to direct facebook's response to a URL outside of the load balancer, while sending the user to the same page, but inside the load balancer, when they submit.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an onclick event from what I've seen and from looking at the code.  The closest thing is setting an onvalidate function which gets called when the user clicks submit.